# How to make animate dealing cards of deck in Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I'm starting to learn unity not long ago. Right now, I'm having an issue with dealing cards animation and show it to the players,

looks like:

[image: animation]

I don't know the algorithm to make it. I've tried searching, but didn't find any solution. I am thinking about make a file flash like in the picture to load it when the game starts (very stupid...).

I need some help. If you can, please give me solution !.

Thank you very much.

Comment: For the most part it just seems to tween the cards between their initial position in the center and their final position on the table, plus a sort at the end, which is also not much more than a tween.

Comment: @Bart I have [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php) to make animate when playing cards. But with dealing cards I don't have solution :)

Comment: I am not much of a card player, so what is the difference? The way I would approach this animation is to just tween the cards (showing their backs) into their positions. And for the bottom row, swap them with the actual face-up card when the tween is completed.

Comment: @Bart Right, I understand. Can you give me sample code to make cards animation move from (0,0) to players ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You're going to have to figure that one out. Give it a try. And if you fail (but have code to show) update your question to include what you've tried.

Comment: @Bart I will try again ;). Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 2):

@Bart I did try and have some results :)

My code

```
IEnumerator InitCardWithAnimation(GameObject[] arrayCards)
    {
        SortCards sort = new SortCards();
        arrayCards = sort.SortCard(arrayCards); ;
        Camera cam = Camera.main;
        float height = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
        float widthCard = arrayCards[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x;
        float x = -6 * (widthCard / 3);
        int layer = 1;
        float z = 13;
        foreach (GameObject item in arrayCards)
        {


            GameObject rocketClone = (GameObject)Instantiate(item, new Vector3(0, 0, z), transform.rotation);

            iTween.MoveTo(rocketClone, new Vector3(x, -height / 3, z), 1.5f);
            yield return rocketClone;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

            x += (widthCard / 3);
            //increase ordermin layer
            rocketClone.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder += layer;
            layer++;
            z--;
            arrCard.Add(rocketClone);
        }
    }
```

And preview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an animation, you might be better of lerping the instantiated card position to the final position. You could set a list to check through to see if there is a card in that position, if so move the next card to the next position. Once the back of the card reaches that position, remove the back of the card item and place actual card in the position that the back of the card was moving to. You can then use these positions so when a player moves a card, it can snap and move the other card position.